# How to set the last n bits of a given octet (byte) to zero?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, bit-manipulation

I got a octet (byte) and a number of relevant-bits and I want to keep the first n (relevant-bits) of that given byte and set the remaining bits to zero.

E.g.

The number 217 where the first 4 bits are relevant would convert to 
208

```
0                    0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  ==> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1      1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

The number 255 where the first 8 (or greater) bits are relevant would not change at all

```
0                    0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+  ==> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I wrote this function to solve the problem

```
(defun list-of-bits (integer)
  (let ((bits '()))
    (dotimes (position (integer-length integer) bits)
      (push (ldb (byte 1 position) integer) bits))))

(defun calculate-octet (byte rel-bits)
  (if (< rel-bits 8)
      (parse-integer 
       (FORMAT nil "~{~a~}"
           (replace (list-of-bits byte)
            '(0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0) 
            :start1 rel-bits
            :end1 8
            :start2 0
            :end2 rel-bits))
       :radix 2)
      byte))
```

But this solution seems bad for two reasons

1. it splits the integer into a list before processing it
2. it prints the list into a string which is again parsed

I know that common-lisp provides functions to directly access the bits and bytes (ldb,logbitp) but I could not figure out a way to use them for my problem.

**Is there a way to solve the problem more efficient (or at least more elegant)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ash](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ash.htm) does the trick:

```
(defun calculate-octet (byte bits)
  (let ((shift (- 8 bits)))
    (ash (ash byte (- shift)) shift)))
```

Testing:

```
? (calculate-octet 217 4)
208
? (calculate-octet 255 8)
255
```

Comment: works like a charm, only problem occurs when bits is greater 8. Simple if would fix that.

Comment: @Sim Your question was about an octet, so I assumed 8. You can either make the number of bits a parameter, or better, express the number of bits you want to set to 0.

Comment: no you are right, my bad, I assumed that a negative shift (e.g. 8 - 9 = - 1 -> shift = -1) would affect the number. But when testing it with a number greater 8 it turned out to work properly

Answer (score 8):

```
CL-USER 6 > (mask-field (byte 4 4) 217)
208
```

Note also that it does not mask the field of the original number, but returns a new number with the bit field masked.

Comment: wouldn't it have to be `(mask-field (byte 8 (- 8 relevant-bits)) byte)` to work?

Comment: @Sim: not really, we want to mask 4 bits, not 8. `byte` takes *size* and *position*. We want to mask 4 bits from position 4 onwards. We don't want to mask 8 bits from position 4 onwards. For this question it makes no difference, since there are only 8 bits in the byte. Thus the bits from 0..7 are interesting and the bits from 8.. onwards are zero anyways.

Comment: I wonder why this is not accepted answer, it seems to be most natural solution.

Answer (score 7):

There are already three answers, so I may as well add another two:

No one suggested [`DPB`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dpb.htm) yet.  Always nice with a nod to the PDP-10.

```
(defun calculate-octet (byte bits)
  (dpb 0 (byte bits bits) byte))
```

Again with the [`LOGAND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_logand.htm).

```
(defun calculate-octet (byte bits)
  (logand byte (ash -1 (- 8 bits))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is LOGAND.

```
(defun calculate-octet (byte rel-bits)
  (ecase rel-bits
    (0 0)
    (1 (logand byte #b10000000))
    (2 (logand byte #b11000000))
    (3 (logand byte #b11100000))
    (4 (logand byte #b11110000))
    (5 (logand byte #b11111000))
    (6 (logand byte #b11111100))
    (7 (logand byte #b11111110))
    (8 byte)))
```

Comment: if you substitute `ecase` with `case` and `(8 byte)` by `(otherwise byte)` it works like a charm

Comment: Here's a suitable situation for logandc2: `(logandc2 byte (1- (expt 2 rel-bits)))`

Comment: Hardcoded masks for every value of `rel-bits`? This is not Lispy. -1